# Importing Plotly takes too much time to load from cgi-python script

Tags: python, cgi, plotly

While running a Python script from cgi-apache, importing plotly in the script is taking approx 1 minute. What can be the solutions to reduce import time ?

While running script locally, it takes only 3s to import plotly.

Comment: There is actually an issue reported on plotlys loading performance, however the cgi-apache is not mentioned there: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/740

Comment: I understood that it requires about 3s to import plotly but when I run the script from apache-cgi and run the same script from server, it is taking approx. 1 minute to import.